# Dynamic Keys and value type checking in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, type-conversion

I have started learning typescript. I am sure there might be a similar ticket as this but wanted a quick view into this.

```
i have keys
type keys = 'a' | 'e' | 'i' | 'o' | 'u';
I want these to restrict the possible a keys in an object
```

```
{
numbers : number;
symbols : string;
[key : keys] : string | number | boolean;
}
```

However i get this error `An index signature parameter type cannot be a union type. Consider using a mapped object type instead.`
so i tried

```
{
numbers : number;
symbols : string;
[key in keys] : string | number | boolean;
}
```

but I got `another error` from TSLint.
I hope if somebody can help me out with these with examples why and how do they vary? and solution Please.

The result I want is

```
key with only values of a, e, i, o, u and these Keys can have any of the string, number, boolean types of values.
```

Answer (score 1):

[Mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types) are similar to [index signatures](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#indexable-types), but they are not the same.  As you discovered, the keys of index signatures can only be exactly `string` or `number`.  Mapped types allow you to specify a narrower set of keys, but you can't add other properties to a mapped type.

What you *can* do is use an [intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#intersection-types):

```
type X = {numbers: number; symbols: string} & {[K in keys]: string | number | boolean}

// type X = {
//  numbers: number;
//  symbols: string;
// } & {
//  a: string | number | boolean;
//  e: string | number | boolean;
//  i: string | number | boolean;
//  o: string | number | boolean;
//  u: string | number | boolean;
// }
```

This is essentially the same as what you want, since the intersection `A & B` means that you must conform to both `A` and `B`.

Another way to represent this type is to use a mapped [conditional](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#conditional-types) type for the whole thing instead of an intersection.  This will be more complicated-looking for you, but evaluates to something nicer for people to use:

```
type Y = { [K in "numbers" | "symbols" | keys]:
  K extends "numbers" ? number :
  K extends "symbols" ? string :
  string | number | boolean };

// type Y = {
// a: string | number | boolean;
// e: string | number | boolean;
// i: string | number | boolean;
// o: string | number | boolean;
// u: string | number | boolean;
// numbers: number;
// symbols: string;
```

Either way should work.  Hope that helps; good luck!

Answer (score 0):

```
    type keys =  'a' | 'e' | 'i' | 'o' | 'u'

    type Dynamic = {
      [index in  keys]: string | number | boolean
    }&{
      numbers : number;
      symbols : string;
    }
```

Comment: Answers with explanation are more acceptable + votable